# Проблема с gzip. Не читаемый текст

Tags: node.js, binary, gzip, buffer, deflate

Не могу разобраться как раскодировать ответ сервера, в utf8.
Судя по 1f 8b, ответ сжат с помощью gzip.
Использую модуль zlib node JS, получаю, что-то такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ответ сервера в binary:
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

headers:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, как это конвертировать в читаемый utf-8

Comment: «получаю, что-то такое» — всё правильно получаете, именно это здесь и закодировано

Comment: «как это конвертировать в читаемый utf-8» — а почему вы решили, что «читаемый utf-8» здесь вообще должен быть?

Comment: К сожалению, точно я не знаю, моё предположение, что должен быть utf8.
На сайте информация в читаемом виде, значит браузер это как-то обрабатывает.
Если это не utf-8, то что тогда?
Не могу понять, как это привести в читаемый вид.
Перепробовал всё(

Comment: Кажется это зашифровано AES
e = zt.AES.decrypt(t, "!Pk`*@pXmM7pEg!GA(q=").toString(zt.enc.Utf8))